# ParseClient.Initialize("", "") crash in FinishedLaunching

Tags: c#, ios, facebook, parse-platform, xamarin

I have Parse 1.3.0 incorporated in my Xamarin MonoGame iOS app. Following the instructions, I do the following in the FinishedLaunching() method:

```
ParseObject.RegisterSubclass<ParseUserData>();
ParseClient.Initialize("someKey", "someOtherKey");
```

I tested the release build (not App Store build since it won't deploy) of my app in on an iPhone 4 & 5 and iPad and all went well with and without an internet connection. I did not test on iPod (which the Apple reviewer used) since I don't have access to one and its discontinued. After submission for review I got a rejection from Apple citing a crash on app startup. According to the crash log listed below, it seems to be due an exception raised by ParseClient.Initialize. I personally have not been able to replicate the error on any iPhone or iPad since I don't know what variables were different for the reviewer and what exactly caused the exception. I would appreciate tips on how to fix this issue.

```
Hardware Model:      iPod5,1
2014-11-06 01:21:36.044 TopShooteriOS[1558]: <Error> Could not successfully update network info during initialization.
2014-11-06 01:21:37.046 TopShooteriOS[1558]: <Error> assertion failed: 12B411: libxpc.dylib + 51955 [04694BEB-256F-3132-A00F-0C82B79BC689]: 0x7d
2014-11-06 01:21:37.700 TopShooteriOS[1558]: <Warning> system library is /usr/lib/libSystem.dylib.
2014-11-06 01:21:37.704 TopShooteriOS[1558]: <Warning> Phone Model is iPod5,1.
2014-11-06 01:21:37.770 TopShooteriOS[1558]: <Error> Could not successfully update network info during initialization.
2014-11-06 01:21:37.869 TopShooteriOS[1558]: <Warning> Attempting to badge the application icon but haven't received permission from the user to badge the application

3   TopShooteriOS                   0x0111da22 mono_handle_native_sigsegv (mini-exceptions.c:2360)
4   TopShooteriOS                   0x01122c46 sigabrt_signal_handler (mini-posix.c:206)
5   libsystem_platform.dylib        0x374b90a0 0x374b5000 + 16544
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x374bed0e 0x374bb000 + 15630
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x373de934 0x37395000 + 301364
8   TopShooteriOS                   0x011d03c8 monotouch_unhandled_exception_handler (monotouch-glue.m:1665)
9   TopShooteriOS                   0x0111de08 mono_invoke_unhandled_exception_hook (mini-exceptions.c:2703)
10  TopShooteriOS                   0x0112a61e mono_thread_abort_dummy (mini.c:2826)
11  TopShooteriOS                   0x0111d5c6 mono_handle_exception_internal (mini-exceptions.c:1713)
12  TopShooteriOS                   0x0111c642 mono_handle_exception (mini-exceptions.c:1937)
13  TopShooteriOS                   0x011163e6 mono_arm_throw_exception (exceptions-arm.c:159)
14  TopShooteriOS                   0x002fe91c rethrow_exception + 64
15  TopShooteriOS                   0x001e167c mscorlib__System_Lazy_1_get_Value + 48
16  TopShooteriOS                   0x00972e24 Parse_iOS__Parse_PlatformHooks_get_ApplicationSettings + 16
17  TopShooteriOS                   0x00966120 Parse_iOS__Parse_ParseClient_get_ApplicationSettings + 68
18  TopShooteriOS                   0x00b7e148 Parse_ParseClient_get_InstallationId + 248
19  TopShooteriOS                   0x00b7df50 Parse_ParseClient_Initialize_string_string + 340
20  TopShooteriOS                   0x000dc4c8 TopShooteriOS__TopShooteriOS_Program_FinishedLaunching_MonoTouch_UIKit_UIApplication + 324
21  TopShooteriOS                   0x002d6408 wrapper_runtime_invoke_object_runtime_invoke_dynamic_intptr_intptr_intptr_intptr_0 + 196
22  TopShooteriOS                   0x01129dd8 mono_jit_runtime_invoke (mini.c:6727)
23  TopShooteriOS                   0x01171d46 mono_runtime_invoke (object.c:2831)
24  TopShooteriOS                   0x00fcae2c native_to_managed_trampoline_1 (registrar.m:48)
25  TopShooteriOS                   0x00fccb10 -[AppDelegate applicationDidFinishLaunching:] (registrar.m:759)
```